# Laravel, how to eliminate some of the "pluck" value for dropdown selection?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

**Controller**

```
$getFurniture = Furniture::where('active', 1)->pluck('fur_name', 'id');
dump($getFurniture);
```

[image]

**Table**

[image]

As you can see, the codes return all the value from the "furnitures" table, how do I eliminate the value that contain from "furniture_prices" table in the pluck queries result? So in this case, user can select "fur5", "fur6", "fur8", "fur9", "fur10", "fur11" and fur12"

Comment: How are `furniture` and `furniture_prices` related?

Comment: furniture_prices table is related by fur_id to furniture table id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you already have the relationship defined. Use the [`doesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) method:

```
Furniture::where('active', 1)->doesntHave('furniturePrices')->pluck('fur_name', 'id');
```

If the relationship doesn't exist yet, create `hasOne()` or `hasMany()` relationship first:

```
public function furniturePrices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FurniturePrice::class, 'fur_id');
}
```

Comment: where should I put the relationship at? is it in Furniture(furnitures) model or FuniturePrice(furniture_prices) Model?

Comment: oh my...works like a charm! straight forward answer with explanation, thank you very much

Comment: if i may ask, is there an alternative to this in raw queries? just asking

Comment: @learnprogramming you can always do the same with raw queries, but if you want to keep your app maintainable, [you should use Eloquent where possible](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#prefer-to-use-eloquent-over-using-query-builder-and-raw-sql-queries-prefer-collections-over-arrays) as I advice in my best practices repository.